# Oracle Inner/Outer/Full Join

Tags: oracle, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have two tables table1 and table2

In table1 i have two columns table1.userid and table2.full_name and in table2 i have two columns table2.userid and table2.ssn

I want records where userid present in both table1 and table2.

Records having userid present in table1 should be ignored if they are present in table2.  If not present than want data from table1 also. Also want rest of the data from table2.

Should i use inner/outer/full join?

Can you please help me for the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `userid`s that are present in *both* tables, then use `inner join`:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid;
```

If you want *all* the `userid`s in `table1`, then use `left outer join`:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid;
```

If you want *all* the `userids`s in both tables, then use `full outer join`:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid;
```

Comment: I have table1 with values 1|john|11 , 2|christine|22, 3|xavi|1111, 4|peter|666 and table2 with values 3|33, 4|44. Than 3 and 4 userid are common in both the tables. If they are common than i want to fetch it from table2 not from table1. Also remaining userid from table1 and table2 should come in my select query. So the final result shuld be like 1|john|111, 2|christine|22, 3|xavi|33, 4|peter|44.

Comment: @user1251973 . . . Either delete this question or modify it, with sample data and the results that you want.